# Swing focus lost inputverifier

Tags: java, swing, focus, listeners, inputverifier

I have a frame with some `JTextFields` on it. When the user tabs out from a `JTextField`, I execute **custom logic** in the `FocusTraversalPolicy`, which sets some properties and based on them the `FocusTraversalPolicy` decides where should the focus go next. So far so good.

But I want this **custom logic** to execute **everytime** the `JTextField` loses focus(in an `InputVerifier`, because there is also validation in it).

Now the problem and the question: If the user leaves the field with the mouse the `InputVerifier` will be triggered and everything will be fine. But if the user presses `TAB`, both the `FocusTraversalPolicy` and the `InputVerifier` will be triggered and the **custom logic** will be executed twice, which I don't want. How can I detect in the `InputVerifier` that `TAB` was already pressed and don't execute anything? I want to execute the **custom logic** in the `InputVerifier` only when the field is left with the mouse. Or is there a better solution?

Hope my question is clear.

Regards, Petar

Comment: hmmm maybe there are (JTextFields) another Listeners (Focus/Document) in same time, remove that and adds if needed, how is implemented notify(); please check and read  http://tips4java.wordpress.com/?s=focus especially http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/ ,http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/05/09/scrolling-a-form/, http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/formatted-text-field-tips/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up setting a `boolean` flag from the `FocusTraversalPolicy` if the **custom logic** is executed. Then in the `InputVerifier` if it is already executed I don't execute it again. Then I reset the flag.